# How to deploy RAML API's to Mule standalone

Tags: mule, raml, apikit

I have created an API using RAML and I have been able to expose it as a Web site on my local Windows laptop. However, now I need to install Mule standalone on a server an install it there. The tutorial provided for this starts with downloading an APIkit zip file (t-shirt) and placing this file on a folder on the Mule standalone. I would like to know hoe to create this APIkit zip file from a RAML API.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What are some things that have you tried? Please provide examples of what has/hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

The API Kit zip file is nothing but the RAML in a regular zip file. You can install in Mule just like any other mule project. Keep the RAML in `src/main/api`

Comment: Yes, thanks. But, how do I create one? Just SIP all the files in the project?

Comment: Create RAML or zip file?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy it like any normal [Mule installation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/deploying).

Once your Mule Server is up and kicking, you can deploy any apps to it within the "apps" directory:

`/$MULE_HOME/apps/`

And the Mule Server will automatically read them and deploy them for you.